# What is the purpose to use "==#" with empty string?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, map-operator

The following is from vim-sensible plugin:

```
set incsearch
" Use <C-L> to clear the highlighting of :set hlsearch.
if maparg('<C-L>', 'n') ==# ''
  nnoremap <silent> <C-L> :nohlsearch<C-R>=has('diff')?'<Bar>diffupdate':''<CR><CR><C-L>
endif
```

As far as I know, `==#` is "always case-sensitive" operator. But what is the purpose to use it when we are compare something to empty string?

And also, what does the entire `if maparg('<C-L>', 'n') ==# ''` line mean?

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/22.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help maparg()` explains that `maparg('<C-L>', 'n')` will return the normal mode mapping assigned to control-L.

When there is no mapping for `<C-L>`, then it will return an empty string...so it's politely checking for the existence of a mapping before assign the mapping.

Concerning `==#` with an empty string, some plugin authors automatically use `==#` all the time without considering who it may confuse.  :)

Comment: Note the possibility of `empty()` in this case which is clearer, though I am indeed among those who use `==#`/`is#` for comparisons almost every tme—the link in the comments is a good one. (Same reason you should use === in javascript unless you really truly know better.)